# Angular $location.path expression for a URL

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to hide a header element in my AngularJS app based on certain paths. So far I have this:

```
    <header logo="appModel.config.logoUrl" ng-hide="currentPath==='/brandHealth/metricsWidget'"></header>
```

This works fine but when I change `currentPath` to `'/brandHealth/*'` it does not work. I need it to work for all URLs within that `brandHealth` subset. Any way to do this?

Thanks in adv

Comment: The way I have `currentPath` available is through my controllers like this: `$scope.currentPath = $location.path();`

Comment: What router are you using? If you are using UI router this can be done easily with it.

Comment: @apaul Using ngroute

Comment: Maybe look at going to UI router. Partials are easy to do. You can define templates for those partials in the router file. Someone has implemented partials on ngroute here, I feel like that is a cleaner solution- http://blog.richpollock.com/2014/10/angular-js-tabs-directive-with-dynamic-loading-of-partial-templates-and-controllers/

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to:

```
'/brandHealth/metricsWidget'.split('/')[0] === currentPath
```

But, you should do that on your controller

```
$scope.containsPath = '/brandHealth/metricsWidget'.split('/')[0] === currentPath
```

Then in your header element

```
<header logo="appModel.config.logoUrl" ng-hide="containsPath"></header>
```